# Want package.json to depend on specific npm version, and install it?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I want package.json to depend on specific npm version, and install it. I see there is a NVM, but do not know if this addresses my needs. At bare minimum I would like an error if npm does not meet specified version somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the required `npm` version in the `engines` field of the `package.json` for your module:

```
{
  "name": "moduleName",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "~2.4.12"
  }
}
```

As specified in the [npm package.json doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines), this config is advisory - unless the user sets the [`engine-strict`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#engine-strict) config flag.